# Showing correct proof for finding equivalence classes for relation defined on $\mathbb{Z}$ by $aRb$ if $6 \mid (a^2 - b^2)$

Tags: solution-verification, relations, equivalence-relations

For relation defined on $\mathbb Z$ by $aRb$ if $6 \mid (a^2 - b^2)$

I know that the equivalence classes are {0,1,2,3,4,5} but I'm unsure if my method of proof is valid. For the first part of the question, I proved it was an equivalence relation on $\mathbb{Z}$, and now I need to find and prove the equivalence classes.

My thoughts so far:

- Let there be $a,r \in \mathbb{Z}$, so that $6 \mid (a^2-r^2)$.
- I know by Euclidean Division that  $6 \mid (a^2-r^2) \equiv a^2=6q+r^2$ , $q \in \mathbb{Z}$
- Then I also know that $0 \leq r^2 <6$
- If $aRr$, the I know $[a]=[r]$ and also $a\in[r]$***
- Then by transitivity, since I proved (in my homework) $bRa \land aRr \Longrightarrow bRr$ and therefore, $[b]=[a]=[r]$ and $a,b \in [r]$

***Can I state this? Or am I missing something key concept before I can say this?

Any feedback on my train of thoughts is appreciate. Pls let me know if you see any holes of logic that I need to fill.

Comment: Not following.  What does $[i]$ mean?  There are only $4$ squares $\pmod 6$, namely $\{0,1,3,4\}$.

Comment: Sorry, I re-edited it. Is it better?

Comment: Well, no.  What does it mean to say that, say, $1$ is an equivalence class?  And why would $1,5$ be in distinct classes?  After all $1\sim_R 5$.

Comment: The equivalence classes should be $0+6\Bbb Z,\ldots$ instead of $0,\ldots$

Comment: Is the equivalence class $0+6\mathbb{Z}$ because the relation already implies that $a^2-b^2$ is evenly divided by 6?

Answer (score 1):

you can use $\pmod 2$ and $\pmod 3$ to describe things, but the result does not fit that well with $\pmod 6$

We always have $x^2 \equiv x \pmod 2,$ so $a^2 \equiv b^2 \pmod 2$ if and only if $a \equiv b \pmod 2.$   For this calculation, we are left with classses even and odd.

Next, squares are $0 \pmod 3$ or $1 \pmod 3.$  As with 2, what we can tell is whether a number is divisible by $3$ or not divisible by $3$.

The equivalence class could be summarized as YY, YN, NY, NN, where the first yes/no is divisbility by $2,$ the second letter is divisibility by $3$

two numbers are equivalent if and only if they have the same pair of letters